# Double order an SQL statement

Tags: mysql

I have a single MySQL table that has as one of its fields STATE.  This row is field with state names except for a few that are marked as INTERNATIONAL instead of a state name.

What I basically want to do is select all distinct states, ordered alphabetically, then at the end select "International"

International may not always be there so I don't want to just hard code it.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT state, IF(state LIKE 'international', 'zz', SUBSTRING(state,1,1)) AS order_by 
FROM `states`
order by order_by asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guillermo...not sure why I wasn't thinking of unions.  Guess I don't use them enough.  This seems to get me exactly what I need:

```
SELECT DISTINCT state FROM stationslist order by state) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT state FROM stationslist WHERE state = 'International'
```